# Identify new values in Table A and insert them in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: Table A and Table B. B is suppose to contain all Ids from A, and then when I run a query each time I need to check for newly added Ids in A that are not already contained in B, and insert them to B. A is being updated daily with each row having a unique Id.

I only need to record 4 columns from A into B (Id, Region, Department, EntryDate), with EntryDate being the date when Id was added into B. B serves as sort of historic record of when Ids and when they first appeared in A.

What would be the query for inserting this new data from A to B?

Comment: `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Thanks! I realized I had the solution in front of me. You are right, this works.

Comment: @detrraxic NOT EXISTS works fine but you will face performance issue as soon as data grows. See my answer.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it resolves your problem. @detrraxic

Comment: Why do you need a table B anyway ? If you always copy new rows from A into B than B will be an exact copy of A, unless you do updates in A or B that are not synced. Maybe if you explain what you want to achieve we could understand and help better

Answer (score 1):

To identify new value you should add new column to `table A` named `IsTransfered` with `default` value 0.

```
Alter Table A Add IsTransfered BIT Default(0)
```

Then create a job with this query to transfer new value.

```
Begin Transaction 
Begin Try
DECLARE @InsertedIDs Table (ID Int)

Insert B (Id, Region, Department, EntryDate)
Select Id, Region, Department, EntryDate
Output inserted.Id INTO @InsertedIDs 
From A
Where IsTransfered  = 0

Update A
SET IsTransfered = 1
FROM @InsertedIDs I
INNER JOIN A ON I.ID = A.Id

COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK  
END CATCH
```

As you can see in query it updates  `IsTransfered` after transferring new records. And it must be within a transaction.

For more performance gain create a filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FilterdByIsTransfered
    ON A (ID)  
    WHERE IsTransfered = 0;
```

Comment: how will this handle multiple ID, Region, dept combos with different entrydate captured between job runs?

Comment: @RegBes Every time job runs the record with IsTransfered  = 0 will be transferred. Because the script updated IsTransfered  to 1 then these record will not copy in next job.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to create a view? this way no job needs to be run and they will always be in sync.

```
create view b as

Select Id, Region, Department, min(EntryDate) as EntryDate
from a
group by Id, Region, Department
```

Comment: Why do you think no job needs to be run when you create a view ?

Comment: as the view gets its data from the underlying table A in this case, every time A changes and you select data from the B view it will have the new updated data. in essence every time you select data from B it gets the data from A. B has no data in it just a definition on how to get data from A

Comment: And how does view B knows what rows are new and what rows are old ? Your idea is not bad though, the OP wants all new rows from A inserted into B, so actually B will be a copy of A. So in stead of inserting into B he might have enough with this view. But, the question in my mind is, why does he needs a table B anyway if it's a copy of A

Comment: the min(EntryDate) gets the earliest entry date i.e. when it first appeared, and the group by makes sure only one ID, region, dept combo is returned.

Comment: as a side note most of the other solutions mentioned here will fall over if a ID, region, dept combo has 2 entry dates captured into A between when jobs are run

Comment: `most of the other solutions mentioned here will fall over if a ID, region, dept combo has 2 entry dates captured into A between when jobs are run` No sorry that is simply not true

Comment: op requirement "B serves as sort of historic record of when Ids and when they first appeared in A." depending on how you interpret this, the part of fall over or not give correct results is true without some sort of filter condition stopping multiples being inserted into B

Comment: Granted, this might be interpreted like this, I removed that comment

Answer (score 0):

use **EXCEPT Operator** to get new IDs in table A and then use **where .. IN** with **select** to Insert data into table B as follows.

```
INSERT INTO B (Id, Region, Department, EntryDate)
---select new IDs and it's associated values from table a
SELECT Id,
       Region,
       Department,
       EntryDate
FROM   A
WHERE  id IN(
             SELECT DISTINCT id --get new IDs in table a
             FROM   A
             EXCEPT
             SELECT DISTINCT id
             FROM   B)
```

Comment: how will this handle multiple ID, Region, dept combos with different entrydate captured between job runs?

Comment: If there exist a One-to-One Relationship,the query will works, but in One-to-Many Relationship, it is mandatory to put *conditions* in select

Comment: A simple `where not exists` seems easier to use, and my guess is it will perform the same if not better

Comment: In  One-to-Many Relationship it provide difficulties