# How can I solve this sql server scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I do not know how to ask this question but my client asked me like this he wants for example he has a database at `xxx.xxx.xxx.206` a table named `Products` but he also has a database at `xxx.xxx.xxx.246`and also a table called `Products`.

When he inserts a product at `xxx.xxx.xxx.206` it should also be inserted inside Products table in `xxx.xxx.xxx.246` automatically.

triggers came to my mind and I know how to make a trigger but... these kind of stuff he is asking is beyond my levels of knowledge using sql server.

How can I achieve such thing? Should I use triggers for this? but even using triggers how can I make that connection to another database?

Comment: [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) will help

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can be a solution but when the destination is on another server it cause to reduce the performance.

I suggest you to create a job which transfer new inserted record to another server. Adding a new field is required to product table in `xxx.xxx.xxx.206`

```
Alter Table Products Add IsTransfered BIT Default(0)
```

I describe how to use this new filed in my answer to this question:

[Identify new values in Table A and insert them in Table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379560/identify-new-values-in-table-a-and-insert-them-in-table-b/71379818#71379818)